# Cannot find Swift declaration for this class

Tags: ios, frameworks, swift4

Imagine my class is within a dynamic framework (Cocoa Touch Framework) 
and the following files exist in my project:

```
x86_64.swiftdoc
x86_64.swiftmodule
```

Valid Architecture in the project is:

```
arm64
armv7
armv7s
```

My project run in swift simulator but doesn’t work on my device.
What was my issue?

Comment: Which device you use?

Comment: iPhone 5s & iPhone 7 plus

Comment: please refer this link that both device is working on ARMV8 please refer this link:-http://iossupportmatrix.com